# Mechanize: Match fields by label text

Tags: ruby, label, mechanize

When scraping forms, I prefer to look for fields by their labels, since most ids and names of the pages I'm working with are autogenerated, and I can't trust them not to change, and the labels are a lot more descriptive than the names.

Rather than doing this all the time in my script:

```
Mechanize::Page.elements_with 'label'
#...
some_form.field_with(
  some_form.page.label_with(:text => "Address").node['for']
).value = "..."

some_form.field_with(
  some_form.page.label_with(:text => "Zipcode").node['for']
).value = "..."
```

I've started putting a monkeypatch at the top of my script:

```
class Mechanize::Form::Field
  def label_text
    # hack to get the document root
    root = node.ancestors.last
    # look up the label for this field
    label = root.at("label[for=#{dom_id.inspect}]") if dom_id
    label && label.text
  end
 end
```

So I can just do this:

```
some_form.field_with( :label_text => "Address" ).value = "..."
some_form.field_with( :label_text => "Zipcode" ).value = "..."
```

It's a hack, but it works for now. Is there a more elegant solution I could be using?

Comment: So you trust labels not to change but not form field names? It seems to me you should re-examine that.

Comment: I trust labels to change less frequently.

Comment: Changing label text is something that there might be a good reason for and won't break anything. You think that's less likely than something there's no reason for and will break things?

Comment: I think I'd rather not rely on `id`s like `ctl00_m_g_8cecb01f_9b31_4ee6_952c_eeea26359d2d_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl0_TextField` (not an exaggeration). I'm guessing that will change if they change the presentation order of any two fields. And I know I'd rather look that up by the label text of "Description" than have to copy/paste that for every field I'm working with.  Sure the script will break if the labels change, but the labels are a heck of a lot more descriptive for code maintenance purposes.

Comment: You should post the html of the form. Maybe someone can come up with a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution that doesn't involve monkey-patching.  Since the `{element}_with` criteria are matched using `===`, I can pass it a `lambda`:

```
# convenince methods to define matcher lambdas

def has_title expected
  lambda { |node| expected === node['title']
end

def has_label expected
  lambda do |node|
    # hack to get the document root
    root = node.ancestors.last
    dom_id = node['id']
    # look up the label for this field
    label = root.at("label[for=#{dom_id.inspect}]") if dom_id
    # check if it matches
    expected === (label && label.text)
  end
end

some_form.field_with( :node => has_label("Address") ).value = "..."
some_form.field_with( :node => has_label("Zipcode") ).value = "..."
some_form.field_with( :node => has_title("Description") ).value = "..."
...
```

Comment: How do you define the local variable of  `dom_id` in this snippet?

Comment: jonkratz: good call. Looks like that's a holdover from my monkeypatch, when it referred to `Mechanize::Form::Field#dom_id`.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def get_key page, str
  id = page.at("label[text()*='#{str}']")[:for]
  key = page.at("##{id}")[:name]
end
```

And then

```
form[get_key(page, 'Address')] = value
```

That's a little bit cleaner but still a mess. There would need to be a real good reason for me to do that, and I would be annoyed to find it in code that I inherited.